# CMD Command Net User Password expire

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there a CMD command to set an existing Windows user's property's checkbox, "Password never expires", to be unchecked? (Assumption: The checkbox was previously checked before I unchecked it manually to illustrate the box being unchecked)

[image]

I am creating a batch file for windows 10 and I would like to do it programmatically. (I am hardening an OS and baselining it.)

I looked at the CMD command: net user and it does have several password options such as /passwordchg to specify a user can change their own password and /passwordreq which specifies a user must have a password. I find it strange that there isn't one for "Password never expires" (i.e. /passwordexp:{YES|NO}) so my batch file can uncheck that option programmatically. I'm probably missing it in my Google searches but I am unable to find a solution. I include a excerpt of my code:

```
...
...    
net user %Name% /<somePasswordExpireOption:YES
...
...
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how to get the screenshotted Window by clicking, but it can be ran by `lusrmgr.msc`. Is it Windows 10?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps, *as long as they are local not domain*:

```bat
WMIC UserAccount Where "Name='%Name%'" Set PasswordExpires=TRUE
```

Comment: I've found that you have to run this as an Administrator, but that should be obvious.

Comment: Thanks Compo, that command works!! Minor change to your answer, instead of FALSE, I used TRUE to unchecked that box. Thanks so much! I was so consumed in "net user". ugh

Comment: @Allen - Good rule of thumb for the future: if it has anything to do with Windows administration, there's probably a setting for it in `wmic`.